# Craft 3: fetching a single Matrix row by its dropdown field value

Tags: matrix, drop-down

I have 2 Matrix fields in an entry type, both of which use Dropdown fields:

```
Matrix: urls
    address (block type)
        context (dropdown field values include 'own')
        address
        urn

Matrix: logos
   svg (block type)
        usage (dropdown field values include 'monoNeg')
        aspectRatio
        svg (source code)
   img (block type)
        usage (equivalent dropdown field)
        img
```

Entries are assigned to a `footer` Globals field, from which I'm pairing a **urls** value with a **logos** value in a loop to write linked logos.

I can get the relevant URL easily enough with:

```
{% for org in footer.footerAccreditations %}
    {% set orgUrl = org.urls.context('own').one() %}
    {{ orgUrl.address }}
{% endfor %}
```

Which prints the `address` URL just fine.

But the same approach for the `svg` logo isn't working. Either one of the following returns `0`, even when I know for sure that the `org` entry in question has a `monoNeg` SVG source.

```
{% set negLogoDirect = org.logos.usage('monoNeg').one() %}
{{ negLogoDirect|length }}

{% set negLogoTyped = org.logos.type('svg').usage('monoNeg').one() %}
{{ negLogoTyped|length }}
```

If I run through an `all` loop for the logos their `usage` reports exactly as I would expect:

```
{% set orgLogos = org.logos.all() %}

{% for logo in orgLogos %}
    {{ logo.usage }}
{% endfor %}
```

I assume I can make my template more verbose and get what I need, but I don't see why the same approach should work for one Matrix dropdown field and not for another.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is most likely happening because `usage` is ambiguous for your `logos` field, so Craft isn’t sure which column to assign the condition to. If you give the `usage` field within your `img` block type a different handle, you should get reliable results.

Comment: Thanks, Brandon. That makes sense and gets a better outcome. Although, having done that, when I `{% set negLogo = org.logos.usage('monoNeg').one() %}` the returned results are the **total number** of rows in the field, but when I `{% set negLogo = org.logos.usage('monoNeg').all() %}` the returned results are **1**, which is what I want, but the opposite of how I would expect to get there!

Comment: So, even though `.all()` is what returns a single result, I'm doing the following just in case it's ever more than 1: `{% for logo in negLogos|slice(0) %}`.